# Convert TD columns into TR rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

Is there a quick way to translate (using CSS or Javascript) a tables TD into TR, currently I have:

```
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

and I want to translate to:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
```

??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to turn HTML arranged like this:

```
<tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td><td>D</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
```

Into this:

```
<tr><td>A</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>B</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>C</td><td>3</td></tr>
<tr><td>D</td><td>4</td></tr>
```

Correct?

You can do this with Javascript, however, it is difficult to suggest a method with out knowing more about the structure of your site/HTML files. I'll give it a go.

Assuming your `<table>` tag comes with an id (like this: `<table id="myTable">` you can access it in javascript like this:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
```

You can create a new table like this:

```
var newTable = document.createElement('table');
```

Now you need to transpose the old tables rows into the new tables columns:

```
var maxColumns = 0;
// Find the max number of columns
for(var r = 0; r < myTable.rows.length; r++) {
    if(myTable.rows[r].cells.length > maxColumns) {
        maxColumns = myTable.rows[r].cells.length;
    }
}


for(var c = 0; c < maxColumns; c++) {
    newTable.insertRow(c);
    for(var r = 0; r < myTable.rows.length; r++) {
        if(myTable.rows[r].length <= c) {
            newTable.rows[c].insertCell(r);
            newTable.rows[c].cells[r] = '-';
        }
        else {
            newTable.rows[c].insertCell(r);
            newTable.rows[c].cells[r] = myTable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;
        }
    }
}
```

This ought to do what you need.  Be forewarned: not tested.  Working this javascript code into an HTML page is left as an exercise for the reader.  If anyone spots any errors that I missed, I be gratified if you point them out to me or simply edit to fix :)

Comment: `newTable.rows[c].cells[r] = myTable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;` should be `newTable.rows[c].cells[r].innerHTML = myTable.rows[r].cells[c].innerHTML;`

Comment: and you should add `document.body.appendChild(newTable);` at the end, in order to add the table-element to the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tested function that will transpose a table, and it will preserve any formatting/events you had hooked to any elements within the table (ie: onclicks on cell or cell contents)

```
function TransposeTable(tableId)
{        
    var tbl = $('#' + tableId);
    var tbody = tbl.find('tbody');
    var oldWidth = tbody.find('tr:first td').length;
    var oldHeight = tbody.find('tr').length;
    var newWidth = oldHeight;
    var newHeight = oldWidth;

    var jqOldCells = tbody.find('td');        

    var newTbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");
    for(var y=0; y<newHeight; y++)
    {
        var newRow = $("<tr></tr>");
        for(var x=0; x<newWidth; x++)
        {
            newRow.append(jqOldCells.eq((oldWidth*x)+y));
        }
        newTbody.append(newRow);
    }

    tbody.replaceWith(newTbody);        
}
```

Notes:
- Requires Jquery
- Not tested on very large tables
- Will likely crap out on tables with spanned columns/rows
- Will likely crap out on tables with any combination of thead/th

So as long as your tables have no spanned cells and doesnt use thead/th, should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution, in this case this was for for mobiles and tablets, remove the media queries and the th position absolute and u have it!

based on this:

```
table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
display: block; 
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone needs it: I converted TR to TD by CSS (a table with one column).
Apply from second line until end of the table on TR the code below:

```
<tr style="float:left;">
```

Also used the code below to show each 3 rows as one line of 3 columns:

```
<tr style="float:left; width:33.33%;">
```