# HTML table conversion with jQuery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Do you know any plugin or ready-to-use solutions to convert `table #1` into `table #2` and potentially back again?

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Seefeld/4BJKa/)**

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of `http://stackoverflow.com/a/2730993/405673`

Comment: not exactly, this table uses `<thead>` & `<tbody>` which require an extra step to solve

Answer (score 1):

THe word you are looking for is transpose a table

I made this function look at it if you have questions about how it works ask me.

http://jsfiddle.net/4BJKa/32/