# How to rotate an asp.net gridview using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I need to rotate a `gridview` using jQuery. What I mean by rotate is to replace the column headers with the row cells of the first column. For example, the HTML output of a simple gridview is the this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Would then be rotated to the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>1</th>
        <th>4</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col3</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to achieve this using jQuery

Comment: A far better method would be to write your own ASP.Net control which formats the table in this manner. Munging it using jQuery is not ideal IMO.

Comment: tried to invert the datasource itself before binding.it works but i dont want a serverside solution.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730699/convert-td-columns-into-tr-rows