# HTML table rows convert to columns using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

using this [`[code]`](http://jsfiddle.net/PhWGF/4/)
 I am able get the html table data as [image: this] 
how can I make the same data as 
[image]

I want to convert second column rows should make as column names and corresponding data should be under that columns

Comment: Have a look at this and do it yourself http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span

Comment: Hi I am to do span I want something like PIVOT to convert rows to columns

Comment: see if this helps u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730699/convert-td-columns-into-tr-rows